# Changing the direction of a point

Tags: java, direction

I was to create a code where I mimic the functions of a robot. Turning and moving and such. I feel as if I'm approaching this in all the wrong ways... When I was writing this I thought I understood the gist of it, if the direction in the constructor is this then if it turn the new direction is this. I tested this and of course I ended up with some real incorrect results. I'm absolutely sure that I don't actually use any of these functions for my object. Can I get a tip about how to work this kind of code?

```
import java.awt.Point;
public class Robot
{
private int x;
private int y;
private int d;
private int p;
public static final int NORTH = 0;
public static final int SOUTH = 1;
public static final int EAST = 2;
public static final int WEST = 3;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Robot
 * @param theX the x coordinate
 * @param theY the y coordinate
 * @param theDirection the direction the robot is facing
 */
public Robot(int theX, int theY, int theDirection)
{
    x = theX;
    y = theY;
    d = theDirection;
}

public void turnLeft()
{
    if(d == NORTH) {
        d = WEST;
    }
    if(d == WEST) {
        d = SOUTH;
    }
    if(d == SOUTH) {
        d = EAST;
    }
    if(d == EAST) {
        d = NORTH;
    }
}



public String getDirection()
{
    if(d == NORTH) {
        return "N";
    }
    if(d == SOUTH) {
        return "S";
    }
    if(d == WEST) {
        return "W";
    }
    if(d == EAST) {
        return "E";
    }   
    return "";
}
}
```

Testing

```
Robot rob = new Robot(20, 20, Robot.SOUTH);
rob.turnLeft;
System.out.println(rob.getDirection);
```

this return S when I think it should actually return E.

Comment: Your turnLeft() is mixing p and d.

Comment: sorry, this was my code before I fixed my p and d i'll edit it!

Comment: wait isn't d the direction?

Comment: @Michael We can answer your question, not asking it :)

Comment: @MarounMaroun I'm lost now :( Is it that I'm not actually asking a question?

Comment: @Michael: I would suggest using an enum for the directions. This will both improve readability and preventing mistakes like messing with variables like d and p.

Comment: Sorry, new to StackOverFLow. don't know how all this works. :(

Comment: @Michael there is a [section in FAQ that describes basic principles of stackoverflow asking](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: @om-nom-nom too long, but I better read it now! :'(

Answer (score 1):

You need else if. When you turn left you assign a new value to d which is matching the condition of the following if statements.

Comment: I see, you can't just have entire if statements!

Comment: @Michael You can. But think about this: 1st) d is North, so you enter the brackets of the first `if`. You set it to be West. 2nd) d is West, so you enter the brackets on the second `if`. You set it to be South. (..) And so on. That's what Mitch is trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

Your `turnLeft` method is not quite right.
Here's the code by using `if`:

```
public void turnLeft() {
  if (d == NORTH) {
      d = WEST;
  } else if (d == WEST) {
      d = SOUTH;
  } else if (d == SOUTH) {
      d = EAST;
  } else if (d == EAST) {
      d = NORTH;
  }
}
```

Here's the code by using `switch..case`

```
public void turnLeft() {

  switch (d) {
    case NORTH: d = WEST; break;
    case WEST: d = SOUTH; break;
    case SOUTH: d = EAST; break;
    case EAST: d = NORTH; break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Alexander is right, in OP's case (without else if) you would enter each `if` since you're overwriting the tested value.

Answer (score 1):

**Enum**

```
public enum Direction {
    private String name;
    private String indicator;

    public Direction(String name, String indicator) {
        this.name = name;
        this.indicator= indicator;
    }

    // getters

    NORTH("North", "N"),
    EAST("East", "E"),
    SOUTH("South", "S"),
    WEST("West", "W");
}
```

Next you can easily do this:

```
turnLeft() {
   switch (d) {
        case Direction.NORTH: return Direction.WEST;
        case Direction.WEST:  return Direction.SOUTH;
        case Direction.SOUTH: return Direction.EAST;
        case Direction.EAST:  return Direction.NORTH;
    }
}

getDirection() {
    return d.getIndicator();
}
```

This way you can get rid of the four static int (`NORTH`, `WEST`, `EAST`, `SOUTH`) and change `int d` into `Direction d`. I would really recommend using an `enum` for this. Just to be typesafe.

Comment: you should at the fact, that the type of d has to be changed to `Direction` - just for completeness

Comment: @MarcoForberg: Perhaps you read my answer just before my edit. I've made a small edit in which I've made a note of it.

Comment: `short` is a basic type, you can't use it as a variable name so this one won't compile unless you replace `String short` with something else.

Comment: @StepTNT: Superb for noticing this. I am at work so don't have an IDE at hand, will change it right away.

Answer (score 0):

What's the `p` var that you're using?
Your current direction is stored in `d`

```
...
d = theDirection;
...
```

You should try with this one:

```
public void turnLeft()
{
    if(d == NORTH) {
        d = WEST;
    }
    if(d == WEST) {
        d = SOUTH;
    }
    if(d == SOUTH) {
        d = EAST;
    }
    if(d == EAST) {
        d = NORTH;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Just to clarify.

You wrote something like

```
if(p == SOUTH) {
        d = EAST;
    }
```

So you're checking if `p` is SOUTH and not `d`.

You're not using `p` anywhere so it will never be SOUTH, that's why your `turnLeft()` method does absolutely nothing!

Comment: the p var is another part of my code where I have to return the point at which the robot lies. I think I just messed up my code... and added p there by mistake.. oh dear

Comment: Yeah, I think you've messed it up because in your `getDirection()` you're doing it right!

Comment: Thank you! With all this information I can finish the rest of the code now! :)

Comment: @StepTNT There is a difference between helping someone learn how to accept/vote, and asking them to accept/vote for *your* content. the first is OK; the second is not.

Answer (score 0):

1st) you should really clean up your p and d stuff ;) i suggest to call d "direction"

2nd) you should rearrange your int constants for directions in clockwise order. so you could reduce your `turnLeft()` method to a single line of code. You could order them this way:

```
public static final int NORTH = 0;
public static final int EAST = 1;
public static final int SOUTH = 2;
public static final int WEST = 3;
```

3rd) for testing you should use JUnit:

```
@Test
public void turnLeft() {
    Robot rob = new Robot(20, 20, Robot.SOUTH);
    rob.turnLeft;
    assertEquals("E", rob.getDirection);
    rob.turnLeft;
    assertEquals("N", rob.getDirection);
    rob.turnLeft;
    assertEquals("W", rob.getDirection);
    rob.turnLeft;
    assertEquals("S", rob.getDirection);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone ever neeeded, here is a solution for turning either way:

```
public enum Direction {
    UP,
    LEFT,
    DOWN,
    RIGHT;

    Direction turnLeft() {
        int turnLeft = 1;
        return getDirectionByOrdinalMovingClockwise(turnLeft);
    }

    Direction turnRight() {
        int turnRight = -1;
        return getDirectionByOrdinalMovingClockwise(turnRight);
    }

    Direction turnAround() {
        int turnAround = 2;
        return getDirectionByOrdinalMovingClockwise(turnAround);
    }

    private Direction getDirectionByOrdinalMovingClockwise(int moveBy) {
        var thisDirectionOrdinal = ordinal();
        int newDirectionOrdinal = (thisDirectionOrdinal + moveBy) % enumElementsCount();
        if (newDirectionOrdinal < 0) {
            newDirectionOrdinal = enumElementsCount() + newDirectionOrdinal;
        }
        return values()[newDirectionOrdinal];
    }

    private int enumElementsCount() {
        return values().length;
    }

}
```